# how can i write the function definitions that have the following OCaml types

Tags: function, types, ocaml

I'm taking programming languages course and in this course we study some OCaml. I need function definition of the this OCaml types.

```
('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> ('a -> 'b) * 'b
```

How can I write a function of this ocaml type?
I tried some functions and one of these was very close and that is

```
let func x y = (x, (x y));;
```

this gives

```
val func : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> ('a -> 'b) * 'b = <fun>
```

i confused about the first part; `('a -> 'a -> 'b)` 
a function takes 'a and 'a and 'b ('a means should be any type)

Comment: Have you learned about currying and/or partial function application yet? *nudge nudge*

Comment: i've learned currying and partial functions means like let ... in? @glennsl

Comment: Currying means a function only takes one argument, but can "simulate" multi-argument functions by retuning another function that takes the next argument. That's why there's arrows not just between the last argument and the return type, but also between arguments. Partial function application means applying some but not all arguments to a function and returning a function that only takes the remaining arguments. Partial function application works very well with currying because applying some but not all arguments will automatically return the appropriate function.

Comment: So if you have a function `'a -> 'b -> 'c` and apply just an `'a`, you'll get a `'b -> 'c` function. `let f x y = x + y;; let g = f 2;; let x = g 4;;`

Comment: Comments aren't the best medium to explain this, but if you understand currying and partial function application you'll easily solve this exercise. So I'd recommend you go back through the learning material and make sure you really understand it.

Comment: i understand the idea but again i cannot write the function anyways, i will try. can i ask another question? let rec myfunc foo =
match foo with
| ((x, y), z)::t -> x (y + z + (myfunc t))
| _ -> 1 in
myfunc ......... i need to complete the blank and i understood the but after in i really do not know what to do.  if the head of tail is ((x, y), z) then x times (y+z+ recursive call for the tail if not then 1 in .... i didn't understood this part. question is like "Fill in the region marked as ........ with an expression that (1) makes the code check correctly" @glennsl

Comment: You should post this as a proper question where you show your attempt, explain your reasoning and what doesn't work. It's not easy to comprehend from a comment, and it won't help anyone else if it's answered in a comment either.

Answer (score 0):

The type `('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> ('a -> 'b) * 'b` is a type of a function that takes two arguments.

The first argument is a function itself that takes two values of arbitrary type `'a` and returns an element of some arbitrary type `'b` (that could also be `'a`, i.e., it is not restricted).

The second argument is a value of type `'a` the same that is accepted by a function that is passed as the first argument.

The return value is a pair. The first constituent of the pair is a unary function that takes an argument of type `'a` and returns a value of type `'b`. The second constituent is a value of type `'b`.

You should think of this task like it is a puzzle. You have only two instruments at your disposal a function `('a -> 'a -> 'b)` and a value of type `'a`. So the question is what operations you should do with those two values, to get the result

Hint1: start with the function application operator.

Hint2: the answer is very simple and small, so if you're getting something very big, then you're on a wrong path.